# Why can't I get audio to play with pygame only once?

Tags: pi-3, audio-playback, pygame

I'm sorry if this has been answered, I looked and cannot find the solution.

So I'm trying to play a sound only once from a raspberry pi using pythons pygame library. The raspi is hooked up via hdmi and sound is configured correctly. My original sound file was created and exported from Adobe Audition. I tried to export from audacity with the same results. I've even tried different formats. I also downloaded someone else's example with audio files and I get the same results. I've tried pre_init() with various settings, nothing here effected the non-working examples below.

This code plays the file fine, but it repeats over and over:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame.mixer
import os

from pygame.mixer import Sound
pygame.mixer.quit() #Sound does not play without this line
pygame.mixer.init()

try:
  hello = Sound(os.path.join("music","Hello.ogg"))
  while True:
    hello.play()

except:
  raise UserWarning, "could not load sound file"
```

I've tried the below but when I run it, it pauses for a second and acts like it ran fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame.mixer
import os

from pygame.mixer import Sound
pygame.mixer.quit() #Sound does not play without this line
pygame.mixer.init()

try:
    hello = Sound(os.path.join("music","Hello.ogg"))
    hello.play(0)

except:
    raise UserWarning, "could not load sound file"
```

and I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame.mixer
import os

from pygame.mixer import Sound
pygame.mixer.quit() #Sound does not play without this line
pygame.mixer.init()

try:
  hello = Sound(os.path.join("music","Hello.ogg"))
  i = 0
  while (i < 3):
      hello.play()
      i = i + 1
except:
  raise UserWarning, "could not load sound file"
```

Can you decipher from these previous examples why I can't get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to fix this, but I found that the script ended before the audio has a chance to play. So to fix that I added:

```
time.sleep(hello.get_length())
```

to the script and it works fine now. So the full script looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import pygame
import os

pygame_init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('music','Hello.ogg'))
sound.play()
time.sleep(sound.get_length())
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pythonic Approach

If your objective is to play the sound as part of special effects (say as a part of a game) your python based approach is more appropriate.

---

## Shell Scripting

Assuming your objective is simply to play a single file once there are much simpler ways than writing a python script

My personal favorite for playing mp3 files is `mpg123` which I install using

`sudo apt-get install mpg123`

and to launch it

`mpg123 <filename>`

to suppress the verbose o/p execute like so

`mpg123 -q <filename>`

since mpg123 doesnt play ogg files,

I use `ogg123` which is available in the `vorbis-tools` package

`sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools`

and execute like so

`ogg123 -q <filename>`

---

Several times the related question has come up - how to play a song on startup:

`nano /etc/rc.local`

```
# other initialization on top

mpg123 -q /home/pi/coolsong.mp3 &
exit 0
```

note the trailing `&` will launch the process in the background and let the boot process complete when `exit 0` executes

---

## Hybrid Approach

One another indirect way is use python to launch `ogg123` or `mpg123` using the `subprocess` module [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) like so

`p = subprocess.Popen(args)`

and you can either [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) or poll for the process to [exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.exit).

The indirect approach is generally useful if you don't need total control over the playback but just a simple interface. Sometimes I use it to play a song for a certain duration and stop by having a timer callback terminate the process